# Excel number format to text

Tags: excel, vba

In an excel sheet column there are entries with %, $ symbols that are coming as the cell's number format while some entries have %, $ symbols explicitly entered in the cells (not as number format). Also there are cells with a mix of alphabets, numbers and special symbols and white space.

I am looping over these cells one by one and trying to put to a different range. I am trying to fill the destination cell with the currentlocation cell's exact value being shown in the cell (including number format) as string value.

The problem I am facing is that in the destination cells the displayed value is not matching correct to the current location cell.
I have tried-

```
DestinationCell.Value = CurrentLocationCell.Text 
DestinationCell.NumberFormat ="@"
```

But it didn't work, I wanted to somehow use

```
DestinationCell.Text = CurrentLocationCell.Text
```

but VBA throws an exception if "DestinationCell.Text" is used.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [`Range.Text`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.text) documentation:

> Returns the formatted text for the specified object. Read-only **String**.

Try flipping the order: first change the number format of the destination cell to Text, then write the `CurrentLocationCell.Text`

```
DestinationCell.NumberFormat ="@"
DestinationCell.Value = CurrentLocationCell.Text
```